# How to fetch key of a hash through values in Hash of Arrays

Tags: perl

Below is the small code snippet i have created using Hash Key and Hash Value which is an array.
And my input is Hash value (Array in this case) , i have to search for all the arrays in $ENV hash and fetch the hash key

Example if i search for m3d1 , the output should be TEST3

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Data::Dumper;
  my %ENV;
  
  $ENV{"TEST3"}=["m3d1","m3d2"] ;
  $ENV{"TEST4"}=["m4d1","m4d2"] ;
  $ENV{"TEST5"}=["m5d1","m5d2"] ;
  $ENV{"TEST6"}=["m6d1","m6d2"] ;
  print Dumper \@keys;
  print Dumper \@values;
```

Is it possible , or is there a better design ?

Comment: Don't use `%ENV` as a variable name. There's an existing variable by that name.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. We can visit every value in the data structure until we find the one that matches.

You didn't say what the strings represent, to I'm going to call `TEST3` a group, and I'm going to call `m3d1` a host. The following snippets don't assume a host is preset in only one of group.

```perl
my @groups;
for my $group (keys(%ENV)) {
   for my $host (@{ $ENV{$group} }) {
      if ($host eq $target_host) {
         push @groups, $group;
      }
   }
}

die("Not found\n") if !@groups;

say for @groups;
```

---

But this isn't efficient. If you were planning on doing many lookups, this would be slow.

Let's start by turning the structure inside out.

```perl
my %groups_by_host;
for my $group (keys(%ENV)) {
   for my $host (@{ $ENV{$group} }) {
      push @{ $groups_by_host{$host} }, $group;
   }
}
```

The above produces

```perl
my %groups_by_host = (
   m3d1 => [ "TEST3" ],
   m3d2 => [ "TEST3" ],
   m4d1 => [ "TEST4" ],
   m4d2 => [ "TEST4" ],
   m5d1 => [ "TEST5" ],
   m5d2 => [ "TEST5" ],
   m6d1 => [ "TEST6" ],
   m6d2 => [ "TEST6" ],
);
```

Then, searching becomes instantaneous.

```perl
my $groups = $groups_by_host{$target_host}
   or die("Not found\n");

say for @$groups;
```

Comment: i get Global symbol "$key" requires explicit package name at test.pl .guess its groups , Thanks

Comment: Fixed. // I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Thank you , this seems to be a better approach .

my $target_host="m4d1";
my $groups = $groups_by_host{$target_host}
   or die("Not found\n");

say for @$groups;

I get the below error , Does it print the Key ? 
Bareword "say" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at test.pl line 34.

Comment: does storing non-strings in %ENV even work?

Comment: @ysth, It's a lexical var here. I just assumed the OP was recreating an actual environment without thinking about it. You're right, so so I was wrong in that assumption. Left comment on the OP.

Comment: @LearningCpp One should always use `use strict; use warnings;`, so we leave those out of snippets. Similarly , we leave out the pragma needed to enable `say`. You need to add `use feature qw( say );` or `use 5.010;` or similar.

Comment: Is it possible to copy the  vulae from this array ref to variable ?
my $db_instance = $groups_by_host{$target_host}; 
my $name=@$db_instance;
This copies 1 but not the string

Comment: `my ($name) = @$db_instance;`

Comment: Or use `$name = $group;` instead of `push @groups, $group;`